# Natural Approach text books

Tags: resource-request, reading

I have only found a single example of a [Natural Approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_approach) text book, [Lingua Latina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_%C3%98rberg#Lingua_Latina_Per_Se_Illustrata). Are there any other books in this style available for purchase online?

Comment: This is really broad. Can you narrow down the requirements of "well-known" and specifics about the subject the book should be about?

Comment: Please clarify whether you are looking for specific languages. The natural approach probably has many examples.

Comment: I have updated my question, I am not looking for specific language . Chris can you point me to a few of these many examples ?

Comment: All the textbooks for French, English and German that I used at school used only the target language.

Comment: @chris I have never seen another text book targeting complete beginners written completely in the target language

Answer (score 3):

One series of books for English from the late 1970s to mid 1980s was **Streamline English** by Bernard Hartley and Peter Viney, published by Oxford University Press and now out of print. It consisted of volumes titled *Departures*, *Connections* and *Destinations*. The series was created for use in classrooms rather than for self study. (This series was for British English; apparently, there was also an American version: *American Streamline*.) Our English classes were entirely in English from the very beginning.

My first German textbook was volume 1 of *Deutsch für junge Leute* by Roland Schapers and published by Verlag für Deutsch. This book was entirely in German. It was part of a series of books for use in classrooms, not for self study.

One of the series of books we used for French, *Feu vert au français*, was also entirely in French except for a vocabulary list at the back of the book.

For a Spanish example, see [*Nuevo Ven 1*](http://edelsa.es/venta/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_81_135), published by Edelsa in Spain. You can't preview the book on Edelsa's website or on Amazon, but one of the reviewer comments on Amazon.com says:

> Native English speakers tend to freak out over a book like this, but the fact is that in Europe the majority of school foreign language textbooks don't have a word of the student's native language written in them. The idea is to build the skills you'll eventually need during total immersion in the language.

And yes, another reviewer complains:

> This Spanish book is TERRIBLE. There is not one word of English to explain anything that needs to be explained, therefore the book can only be as useful as your lecturer is.

These are all books for classroom use. The Natural Approach is a language *teaching* approach, not a self-learning approach.